# Inventory cleanup cron job is not running

Tags: magento2, cron, inventory, crontab, magento-cron

The cron job at magento/module-inventory-reservations/etc/crontab.xml does not show up in the general pool in the admin backend. It does not show up in cron_schedule table. It does not run. All other cron jobs are running.

I have run 'bin/magento cron:run', 'update/cron.php' and 'bin/magento setup:cron:run' successfully.

Here is the crontab.xml, this is the default

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="inventory_cleanup_reservations" instance="Magento\InventoryReservations\Cron\CleanupReservations" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 0 * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

cron is installed correctly. It shows magento cron if i run

```
sudo systemctl status cron.service
```

It also shows magento cron if i run

```
crontab -l
#~ MAGENTO START e403599148b405c8cf2c44c4151a6f08a014eb72681640b5388798542dc84acf
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.2 /bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.2 /update/cron.php >> /var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.2 /bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/log/setup.cron.log
#~ MAGENTO END e403599148b405c8cf2c44c4151a6f08a014eb72681640b5388798542dc84acf
```

bin/magento cron:install returns Crontab has already been generated and saved.

Cron is running. The problem is "inventory_cleanup_reservations" is not executed!

How do I enable this specific cron job?
How do I run this?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, until you figure out why your crons are not running, you can use https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2 tool to run the cronjob on demand.

To execute the cronjob, use the command:

```sh
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run inventory_cleanup_reservations
```

Answer (score 0):

Some step to verify cron job in Linux:

1, Check cron job is running

```
sudo systemctl status cron.service
```

2, Add Magento to crontab

```
php bin/magento cron:install
```

3, Check crontab has added Magento cron

```
crontab -l
```

After 00:00 daily use can go to check it.

[image]

So If you want to quickly test this cron you should change it to

```
* * * * *
```

And flush cache

Comment: cron is running fine. the job is just not registering (edited post)